# How to make a call of this recursive Longest Increasing Subsequence function

Tags: java, algorithm, function, recursion, lis

I'm learning about recursion. I have taken as an example the algorithm LIS (Longest increasing subsequence) which given an array:

```
1,2,8,3,6,4,9,5,7,10
```

Find the longest increasing subsequence that would be:

```
1,2,3,4,5,7,10
```

To start with an idea of the operation I was searching on google and I found that function:

```
public static void printLis (int [] lis, int lisIndex, int [] arr, int max) {
    if (max == 0) {
        return;
    }
    if (lis [lisIndex] == max) {
        printLis (lis, lisIndex-1, arr, max-1);
        System.out.print (arr [lisIndex] + "");
    } else {
        printLis (lis, lisIndex-1, arr, max);
    }
}
```

How do I call that function in my example, so that I get the indicated results?

Comment: this piece of code contains few syntax errors. Try submitting a compilable version first.

Comment: In Java, there is a difference between lower and upper case letters. So `printLis` is not the same as `PrintLis`, for example. And `if` is not the same as `If`.

Comment: Do you know Java ? If yes then using this method in a simple java program shouldn't be a problem. Else try to find a sample code for this algo in the language your are familiar with. In case you are not familiar with any language try learning one as you will need some platform to try your algos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Above code is not for calculating LIS. Its for printing the LIS elements. Also the snippet contains syntax error.

Here is a better recursive solution in Java with explanation.

```
class LIS {

    static int max_lis_length = 0; // stores the final LIS
    static List<Integer> maxArray = new ArrayList<>();

    // Recursive implementation for calculating the LIS
    static List<Integer> _lis(int arr[], int indx)
    {
        // base case
        if (indx == 0) {
            max_lis_length = 1;
            return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arr[indx]));
        }

        int current_lis_length = 1;
        List<Integer> currList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i< indx; i++)
        {
            // Recursively calculate the length of the LIS ending at arr[i]
            List<Integer> subproblemList = _lis(arr, i);
            int subproblem_lis_length = subproblemList.size();

            // Check if appending arr[indx] to the LIS ending at arr[i] gives us an LIS ending at 
            // arr[indx] which is longer than the previously
            // calculated LIS ending at arr[indx]
            if (arr[i] < arr[indx] && current_lis_length < (1 + subproblem_lis_length)) {
                current_lis_length = 1 + subproblem_lis_length;
                currList = subproblemList;
            }
        }
        currList.add(arr[indx]);

        // Check if currently calculated LIS ending at
        // arr[n-1] is longer than the previously calculated
        // LIS and update max_lis_length accordingly
        if (max_lis_length < current_lis_length) {
            max_lis_length = current_lis_length;
            maxArray = currList;
        }

        return currList;
    }

    // The wrapper function for _lis()
    static int lis(int arr[], int n)
    {    
        // max_lis_length is declared static above 
        // so that it can maintain its value
        // between the recursive calls of _lis()
        List<Integer> r = _lis( arr, n );
        System.out.println(r);

        return max_lis_length;
    }

    // Driver program to test the functions above
    public static void main(String args[]) {        
        int arr[] = {10, 22, 9, 33, 21, 50, 41, 60};
        int n = arr.length;
        System.out.println(lis( arr, n - 1));


    }
};
```

Output

```
[10, 22, 33, 50, 60]
5
```

#### Complexity

The corresponding tree due to this recursion is like this -

```
              lis(4)
        /        |     \
      lis(3)    lis(2)   lis(1)
     /   \        /
   lis(2) lis(1) lis(1)
   /
lis(1)
```

The time complexity is *exponential*. There will be `2^n - 1` nodes will be generated for a `n` sized array. Plus the space complexity is significant too as we are copying sub-problem's list in function argument. TO overcome this, dynamic programming is used.

Comment: Thanks @KaidulIslam, your solution make me think, is it possible to use maxlength to get the longest array?

I mean, if I get maxlength = 6

And my array was 1,2,5,6,3,4,7,8

Look for ascending progressions of size 6 that would be:

1,2,5,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,7,8

Would be possible?

Comment: Yes, its possible to construct the array elements from the maxLength by traversing from right to left. If you need help, I will provide the code to print the array.

Comment: Now I am trying to implement the solution using maxlength but if you give me your solution with the array return I will be very grateful, so I could compare costs between them.Thanks

Comment: @JackAck, sorry, actually you can't derive the longest array elements by using maxLength. If you apply dynamic programming, then it's possible to get the solution array from backward

Comment: Yes, now I was finding it quite difficult to implement as a solution. Can you leave me the code you said that returned an array without using maxlength to have an idea about how it works? Thanks for all @KaidulIslam

Comment: Yes, but you need dynamic programming for that. Dynamic programming is an advanced topic than recursion. If you're desperate to have the longest array with recursion, I can modify the code. But it won't be using maxLength.

Comment: If you can yes, it would be great, there is no problem. I would like to understand how to solve this code and improve a bit my knowledge about recursion. Thanks @KaidulIslam

Comment: Check updated code. Instead of returning length from each recursive call, I am returning list now. This will now print the longest array.

Comment: Sorry for taking time to answer. I was trying the code and when I send: <10, 22, 9, 33, 21, 50, 41, 60> and the input I get is <10, 33, 50, 60> instead of <10, 22, 33, 50, 60>. Do you know why? 
Sorry if I'm making any mistake and thanks for help me.

Comment: @JackAck I am sorry really, the code had some bug. Now check the update please.

Comment: Now it works perfectly, I will start to look at the operation, thank you very much @KaidulIslam

Comment: You're welcome. To understand recursion and other programming paradigms, I would recommend you to follow a beginner algorithm book from start to end. The way you're following now will take longer time and you can't understand everything intuitively. Good luck!

Comment: I will look it @Kaidul Islam, a. As a curiosity, do you know what cost this algorithm would have?

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry if I disturbed you in any question I'm a bit noob yet, thanks for everything @KaidulIslam.

Comment: No problem, its my pleasure to help folks!

Answer (score -1):

The result is not correct, but you can at least call the function:

```
/**
*
* @author lucius
*/
public class LISQuestion {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    int[] lis = new int[]{1,2,8,3,6,4,9,5,7,10};//empty array where LIS will be stored

    int[] arr = lis; //sequence where LIS should be searched

    int lisIndex = arr.length-1;

    int max = 10;

    printLis(lis, lisIndex, arr, max);
}

public static void printLis (int [] lis, int lisIndex, int [] arr, int max) {
    if (max == 0) {
        return;
    }
    if(lisIndex < 0){
        return;
    }
    if (lis [lisIndex] == max) {
        printLis (lis, lisIndex-1, arr, max-1);
        System.out.print (arr [lisIndex] + " ");
    } else {
        printLis (lis, lisIndex-1, arr, max);
    }

}

}
```

as it is Java, you always need a main method as entry point of the program.

Comment: Thanks @BacLuc now I see how to call the function, I will try to make it show the LIS.